Predicting with LSTM for TS in R
I have a problem with TSLSTM in R. I created a model basing on those arrays: TrainY is 1 column, 3500 rows, TrainX is 3 columns, 3500 rows, PredictX is 3 columns, 50 rown
Data:
> head(y_train)
[1] 879 880 869 888 912 948

> head(TrainX)
   X1   X2    X3
1  5     4     0
2  6     4     0
3  7     4     1
4  8     4     0
5  9     5     1
6 10     5     0

> head(PredictX)
   X1    X2     X3
1  9     55     0
2  10    55     1
3  11    54     1
4  12    53     1
5  1     55     0
6 2      51     0

Model:
library(keras) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(TSLSTM)

TrainY
TrainX
PredictX

LSTM_Model = ts.lstm( #lib: TSLSTM
  TrainY,
  xreg = TrainX,
  tsLag = 2,
  xregLag = 0,
  LSTMUnits = 200,
  DropoutRate = 0,
  Epochs = 2,
  CompLoss = "mape",
  CompMetrics = "mape",
  ActivationFn = "tanh",
  SplitRatio = 0.8,
  ValidationSplit = 0.2
)

Model is created, trained but I see no option to predict using this function for the future. Function "predict" look like it does not consider LSTM_Model as a base to make any forecasting. For example when I use:
predictions = predict(LSTM_Model, PredictX)`

I get an error:
`Error in x - fits : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

No na's are present in any of my data sets. batch_size or horizon are not recognisable as needed parameters.`
What am I doing wrong? What function should I select to use my model for predicting?
I tried different functions created for predicting (predict, forecast) with different sets of parameters but nothing worked.
